# uiviewanimationstate release. program crashes randomly

Tags: iphone, crash, uiviewanimation

The application crashes very rarely. One time it crashed, and I got the following report:

```
[UIViewAnimationState release]:message sent to deallocated instance
```

I am not able to find where is this used. I do not use any animations in my code. What can be the reason for the crash?

this is the code i suspect where it is crashing

```
-(void)showMessageSendingIndicator
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool=[[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init]; 
    self.av1=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sending Message, please wait..." message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
    UIActivityIndicatorView *ActInd=[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    [ActInd startAnimating];
    [ActInd setFrame:CGRectMake(125, 60, 37, 37)];
    [self.av1 addSubview:ActInd];
    [self.av1 show];
    [pool release];
    return; 
}
```

Comment: post the crash log, together with the code where the program stuck in

Comment: the only crash report i got was [UIViewAnimationState release]:message sent to deallocated instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you are setting `av1` to a retained object. Replace this line with something like this:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sending Message, please wait..." message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];

self.av1 = alert;

[alert release];
```

Secondly, you never release `ActInd`. Add `[ActInd release]` before `[pool release]`. This is safe because `av1` retains it when you call `addSubview:`

On a side node, why the `NSAutoreleasePool`? You typically need those on a separate thread, but showing an activity indicator should be done on the main thread.

And also, if you want to follow any conventions, you should replace `ActInd` with `actInd`.

Comment: ya i am calling this in a separate thread.first i was showing this in the main thread ,but then it was taking some delay before the alertview pops up(a bad user experience).now when i use it in a separate thread,its almost instantaneous.

Comment: It's good practice to have all your UI operations on the main thread. UIKit is now mostly thread-safe as of 4.0, but it's still ideal to have anything that's modifying your UI take place on the main rather than secondary threads.